# Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long,

Tags: php, mongodb, date

I have a problem with my code PHP, my database is Mongodb:

I get this error:

> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long,

my code is :

```
<?php echo date('g:i a, F j', $comment['posted_at']); ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

That date value is probably a date string and not a Unix Timestamp as required. Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to correct this:

```
<?php echo date('g:i a, F j', strtotime($comment['posted_at'])); ?>
```

This *assumes* that date is structured in a [format `strtotime()` recognizes](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Comment: i want add date on comments how it works ?

i have this code :

 <?php echo date('g:i a, F j', strtotime($comment['posted_at'])); ?>

but the date is still 1:00 am, January 1

Comment: I'm not sure what you;re looking for but it seems to be a different issue. I would recommend asking this as a new question with a code sample so everyone can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

if you are accessing a MongoDate object, `John Conde`'s answer is wrong.

You must use:

```
<?php echo date('g:i a, F j', $comment['posted_at']->sec); ?>
```

a MongoDate object:

```
MongoDate {
    /* Fields */
    public int $sec ;
    public int $usec ;
    /* Methods */
    public __construct ([ int $sec = time() [, int $usec = 0 ]] )
    public ...... toDateTime ( void )
    public string __toString ( void )
}
```

Comment: Hello,

i want add date on comments how it works ?

i have this code :

 <?php echo date('g:i a, F j', strtotime($comment['posted_at'])); ?>

but the date is still 1:00 am, January 1

Comment: What do you mean by "add date"? Do you want to adjust the date? As you get a unix-timestamp from `mongoDate->sec`, you can use it anywhere. eg: `date('...' , strtotime('+1 day', $d->sec))` or `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $d->sec+3600)`

Comment: ps: do NOT use `strtotime` on `MongoDate`, it's wrong.

Comment: just the date of the comment

Comment: I am sure you are using a MongoDate object in $comment['posted_at'], so you can use my suggest. If you are not sure, you can just do a `var_dump($comment)` to see what objects you are using.